# Invalid syntax for no reason

Tags: function, python-3.x, syntax-error

I cannot figure out why I keep receiving invalid syntax. Here is the function I can't figure out:

```
def coordType():
    coordType = input("Automatic [a] or manual [m] message box coordinates?"
    if coordType.lower not in ("a", "m"):
        print("It must be 'a' or 'm'")
        coordType()
    elif coordType.lower() == "a":
        print("Please put your mouse over the message box")
        time.sleep(5)
        xc, yc = m.position()
        print("Done - " + str(xc) + ", " + str(yc))
    elif coordType.lower() == "m":
        xcoord()
        ycoord()
```

Comment: The invalid syntax error should tell you what line it found it on. Look on that line or one of the ones next to it. What about the ending `)` on your second line there?

Comment: The issue is the brackent in the second line. I would like to add that you forget to add the brackets to coordType.lower in the third line

Answer (score 0):

try to indent everything.
the body of "coordType" is in the same allignment with the title, so it's invalid in python.

Comment: Sorry, please check the post again